# How to use jinja variable inside a variable

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

```
<a href="{{ url_for('osupgrade.download_stage_log',url = result.download_url) }}"  type="submit" target="_self">Download</a>
```

result.download_url --> This also a variable
How can use that? I tried with curly etc, all is failing.

Comment: What is the error? Where does all that come from? What does result contain?

Comment: werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'osupgrade.download_stage_log'. Did you forget to specify values ['url']?

Comment: @Shinratensei it's from flask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you should structure your url:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('osupgrade.download_stage_log', url='') }}{{result.download_url}}"  type="submit" target="_self">Download</a>
```

The value passed to the variable **url** is in a pair of braces isolated from the rest

Comment: werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'osupgrade.download_stage_log'. Did you forget to specify values ['url']?

Comment: @tobin..i get it..can you tell me how to pass multiple values?

Comment: <td><a href="{{ url_for('osupgrade.download_stage_log',hostname = '', dep_id = '') }}{{result.hostname}}{{ result.deployment_id }}"  type="submit" target="_self">Download</a></td>